# Unable to bind data to textbox in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(string InvoiceNo)
        {
            List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> list = new List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity>();
            list = SalesInvoiceManager1.salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(InvoiceNo);
            return list;
        }
```

Above code returns list of some values which i want to bind to textboxes. I cant understand that why these values are not getting in ajax Success  function below:

```
function salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton() {

        var invoice = {};
        var InvoiceNo = $("#txt_InvoiceNo").val();
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/AjaxRequestToServer.aspx/salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton", //URI   
            data: "{InvoiceNo:'" + InvoiceNo + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //Commented code working Fine
                //if (!$.trim(data)) {
                //    alert("What follows is blank: " + data);
                //}
                //else {
                //    alert("What follows is not blank: " + data);
                //}
                //bootbox.alert("Hi", function (e) { });

    //But cannot Bind data in textbox
                $('#txtinvoicevalue').val(data.d[0].totalprice);
                $('#txtTotalDiscount').val(data.d[0].discountamt);         
                $('#txtGrandTotal').val(data.d[0].grandtotal);

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.statusText == "Invalid Request") {
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here Success function working fine. And Commented code also gives right output. But I cant assign the data to textboxes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead and see if that helps, also check to see if you can print the values into your debug console.

pressing F12 will usually show you the development console on browsers, check your script errors there.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But getElementById also not working here. and i got "ReferenceError: val is not defined[Learn More]" this error in console. @mahlatse

Comment: hey.. Thanks.. its working fine... but now i am getting text as undefined in textbox. plz reply.

Comment: Can you check what values you get if you print the the data that you assing to the textbox?

Comment: i dont know how to check.. but i am getting values in back end code. plz tell  me how to check that or how to print that values?

Comment: There are a few ways, use http://www.telerik.com/fiddler to see what values you send to the browser, or you can f12 on your browser, check the network tab on the developer screen for what values are being sent to the client browser

Comment: Hey @mahlatse .. I tried to solved it. But I cant display values in textbox. it only shows "Undefined" in textbox. please see edits.

Comment: Can you post the output of your method ?